# How to solve http11.HeadersTooLargeException?

Tags: java, cookies, http-headers

I getting this error in my project while **adding items in the cart**:

> org.apache.coyote.http11.HeadersTooLargeException: An attempt was made
>   to    write more data to the response headers than there was room
>   available in the buffer.  Increase maxHttpHeaderSize on the connector
>   or write less data into the response headers.

Comment: is error message not clear enough?

Comment: Please share full stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced similar issue and found that it was due to large amount of cookies that got set in response headers.

Please try debugging the coyoteResponse object which has headers field for more information.

Also check: [HeadersTooLargeException - response headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39203084/headerstoolargeexception-response-headers)